# Error occurred while compiling NS3 ,: multiple definition of ' '

Tags: c++, ns-3

This is ssdmodel_ssd_param.h

```
#ifndef _SSDMODEL_SSD_PARAM_H
#define _SSDMODEL_SSD_PARAM_H  

#include "libparam.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern"C"{
#endif
struct dm_disk_if;

/* prototype for ssdmodel_ssd param loader function */
struct ssd *ssdmodel_ssd_loadparams(struct lp_block *b, int *num);

typedef enum {
   SSDMODEL_SSD_SCHEDULER,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCK_COUNT,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_BUS_TRANSACTION_LATENCY,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_BULK_SECTOR_TRANSFER_TIME,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_NEVER_DISCONNECT,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_PRINT_STATS,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_COMMAND_OVERHEAD,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_TIMING_MODEL,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_FLASH_CHIP_ELEMENTS,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_SIZE,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGES_PER_BLOCK,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCKS_PER_ELEMENT,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_ELEMENT_STRIDE_PAGES,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_CHIP_XFER_LATENCY,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_READ_LATENCY,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_WRITE_LATENCY,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCK_ERASE_LATENCY,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_WRITE_POLICY,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_RESERVE_PAGES_PERCENTAGE,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_MINIMUM_FREE_BLOCKS_PERCENTAGE,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_CLEANING_POLICY,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_PLANES_PER_PACKAGE,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCKS_PER_PLANE,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_PLANE_BLOCK_MAPPING,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_COPY_BACK,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_UNITS,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_ELEMENTS_PER_GANG,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_CLEANING_IN_BACKGROUND,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_GANG_SHARE,
   SSDMODEL_SSD_ALLOCATION_POOL_LOGIC
} ssdmodel_ssd_param_t;

#define SSDMODEL_SSD_MAX_PARAM      SSDMODEL_SSD_ALLOCATION_POOL_LOGIC
extern  void * SSDMODEL_SSD_loaders[];
extern  lp_paramdep_t SSDMODEL_SSD_deps[];


static struct lp_varspec ssdmodel_ssd_params [] = {
   {"Scheduler", BLOCK, 1 },
   {"Max queue length", I, 1 },
   {"Block count", I, 0 },
   {"Bus transaction latency", D, 0 },
   {"Bulk sector transfer time", D, 1 },
   {"Never disconnect", I, 1 },
   {"Print stats", I, 1 },
   {"Command overhead", D, 1 },
   {"Timing model", I, 1 },
   {"Flash chip elements", I, 1 },
   {"Page size", I, 1 },
   {"Pages per block", I, 1 },
   {"Blocks per element", I, 1 },
   {"Element stride pages", I, 1 },
   {"Chip xfer latency", D, 1 },
   {"Page read latency", D, 1 },
   {"Page write latency", D, 1 },
   {"Block erase latency", D, 1 },
   {"Write policy", I, 1 },
   {"Reserve pages percentage", I, 1 },
   {"Minimum free blocks percentage", I, 1 },
   {"Cleaning policy", I, 1 },
   {"Planes per package", I, 1 },
   {"Blocks per plane", I, 1 },
   {"Plane block mapping", I, 1 },
   {"Copy back", I, 1 },
   {"Number of parallel units", I, 1 },
   {"Elements per gang", I, 1 },
   {"Cleaning in background", I, 1 },
   {"Gang share", I, 1 },
   {"Allocation pool logic", I, 1 },
   {0,0,0}
};
#define SSDMODEL_SSD_MAX 31
static struct lp_mod ssdmodel_ssd_mod = { "ssdmodel_ssd", ssdmodel_ssd_params, SSDMODEL_SSD_MAX, (lp_modloader_t)ssdmodel_ssd_loadparams,  0, 0, SSDMODEL_SSD_loaders, SSDMODEL_SSD_deps };


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif // _SSDMODEL_SSD_PARAM_H
```

This is ssdmodel_ssd_param.c

```
#include "ssdmodel_ssd_param.h"
#include "bitvector.h"
#include "ssd.h"
static int SSDMODEL_SSD_SCHEDULER_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_SCHEDULER_loader(struct ssd * result, struct lp_block *blk) { 
if (! (result->queue = (struct ioq *)disksim_ioqueue_loadparams(blk, device_printqueuestats, device_printcritstats, device_printidlestats, device_printintarrstats, device_printsizestats))) { // foo 
 } 

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->maxqlen = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCK_COUNT_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCK_COUNT_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i > 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->numblocks = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_BUS_TRANSACTION_LATENCY_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_BUS_TRANSACTION_LATENCY_loader(struct ssd * result, double d) { 
if (! ((d >= 0.0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->bus_transaction_latency = d;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_BULK_SECTOR_TRANSFER_TIME_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_BULK_SECTOR_TRANSFER_TIME_loader(struct ssd * result, double d) { 
if (! ((d >= 0.0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->blktranstime = d;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_NEVER_DISCONNECT_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_NEVER_DISCONNECT_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! (RANGE(i,0,1))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->neverdisconnect = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_PRINT_STATS_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_PRINT_STATS_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! (RANGE(i,0,1))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->printstats = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_COMMAND_OVERHEAD_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_COMMAND_OVERHEAD_loader(struct ssd * result, double d) { 
if (! ((d >= 0.0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->overhead = d;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_TIMING_MODEL_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_TIMING_MODEL_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! (RANGE(i,SSD_SIMPLE_MODEL,SSD_LOGDISK_MODEL))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.ssd_model = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_FLASH_CHIP_ELEMENTS_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_FLASH_CHIP_ELEMENTS_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.nelements = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_SIZE_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_SIZE_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.page_size = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGES_PER_BLOCK_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGES_PER_BLOCK_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.pages_per_block = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCKS_PER_ELEMENT_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCKS_PER_ELEMENT_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.blocks_per_element = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_ELEMENT_STRIDE_PAGES_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_ELEMENT_STRIDE_PAGES_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.element_stride_pages = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_CHIP_XFER_LATENCY_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_CHIP_XFER_LATENCY_loader(struct ssd * result, double d) { 
if (! ((d >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.chip_xfer_latency = d;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_READ_LATENCY_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_READ_LATENCY_loader(struct ssd * result, double d) { 
if (! ((d >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.page_read_latency = d;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_WRITE_LATENCY_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_WRITE_LATENCY_loader(struct ssd * result, double d) { 
if (! ((d >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.page_write_latency = d;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCK_ERASE_LATENCY_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCK_ERASE_LATENCY_loader(struct ssd * result, double d) { 
if (! ((d >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.block_erase_latency = d;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_WRITE_POLICY_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_WRITE_POLICY_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.write_policy = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_RESERVE_PAGES_PERCENTAGE_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_RESERVE_PAGES_PERCENTAGE_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.reserve_blocks = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_MINIMUM_FREE_BLOCKS_PERCENTAGE_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_MINIMUM_FREE_BLOCKS_PERCENTAGE_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.min_freeblks_percent = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_CLEANING_POLICY_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_CLEANING_POLICY_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.cleaning_policy = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_PLANES_PER_PACKAGE_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_PLANES_PER_PACKAGE_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.planes_per_pkg = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCKS_PER_PLANE_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCKS_PER_PLANE_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.blocks_per_plane = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_PLANE_BLOCK_MAPPING_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_PLANE_BLOCK_MAPPING_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.plane_block_mapping = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_COPY_BACK_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_COPY_BACK_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! (RANGE(i,0,1))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.copy_back = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_UNITS_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_UNITS_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0.0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.num_parunits = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_ELEMENTS_PER_GANG_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_ELEMENTS_PER_GANG_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.elements_per_gang = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_CLEANING_IN_BACKGROUND_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_CLEANING_IN_BACKGROUND_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! (RANGE(i,0,1))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.cleaning_in_background = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_GANG_SHARE_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_GANG_SHARE_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.gang_share = i;

}

static int SSDMODEL_SSD_ALLOCATION_POOL_LOGIC_depend(char *bv) {
return -1;
}

static void SSDMODEL_SSD_ALLOCATION_POOL_LOGIC_loader(struct ssd * result, int i) { 
if (! ((i >= 0))) { // foo 
 } 
 result->params.alloc_pool_logic = i;

}

void * SSDMODEL_SSD_loaders[] = {
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_SCHEDULER_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCK_COUNT_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_BUS_TRANSACTION_LATENCY_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_BULK_SECTOR_TRANSFER_TIME_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_NEVER_DISCONNECT_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_PRINT_STATS_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_COMMAND_OVERHEAD_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_TIMING_MODEL_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_FLASH_CHIP_ELEMENTS_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_SIZE_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGES_PER_BLOCK_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCKS_PER_ELEMENT_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_ELEMENT_STRIDE_PAGES_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_CHIP_XFER_LATENCY_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_READ_LATENCY_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_WRITE_LATENCY_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCK_ERASE_LATENCY_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_WRITE_POLICY_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_RESERVE_PAGES_PERCENTAGE_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_MINIMUM_FREE_BLOCKS_PERCENTAGE_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_CLEANING_POLICY_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_PLANES_PER_PACKAGE_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCKS_PER_PLANE_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_PLANE_BLOCK_MAPPING_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_COPY_BACK_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_UNITS_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_ELEMENTS_PER_GANG_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_CLEANING_IN_BACKGROUND_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_GANG_SHARE_loader,
(void *)SSDMODEL_SSD_ALLOCATION_POOL_LOGIC_loader
};

lp_paramdep_t SSDMODEL_SSD_deps[] = {
SSDMODEL_SSD_SCHEDULER_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCK_COUNT_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_BUS_TRANSACTION_LATENCY_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_BULK_SECTOR_TRANSFER_TIME_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_NEVER_DISCONNECT_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_PRINT_STATS_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_COMMAND_OVERHEAD_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_TIMING_MODEL_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_FLASH_CHIP_ELEMENTS_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_SIZE_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGES_PER_BLOCK_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCKS_PER_ELEMENT_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_ELEMENT_STRIDE_PAGES_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_CHIP_XFER_LATENCY_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_READ_LATENCY_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_PAGE_WRITE_LATENCY_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCK_ERASE_LATENCY_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_WRITE_POLICY_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_RESERVE_PAGES_PERCENTAGE_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_MINIMUM_FREE_BLOCKS_PERCENTAGE_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_CLEANING_POLICY_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_PLANES_PER_PACKAGE_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_BLOCKS_PER_PLANE_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_PLANE_BLOCK_MAPPING_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_COPY_BACK_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_UNITS_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_ELEMENTS_PER_GANG_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_CLEANING_IN_BACKGROUND_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_GANG_SHARE_depend,
SSDMODEL_SSD_ALLOCATION_POOL_LOGIC_depend
};
```

**The above two files are two source programs of disksim4.0.I put the above two files into ns-3.26/src/mymodule/model path, and configured the source code name and header file name in wscript file. When compiling, there was a link error. What should I do to solve it?**

```
[ 539/2093] Compiling src/mymodule/model/ssd.c
[ 540/2093] Compiling src/mymodule/model/ssdmodel_ssd_param.c
[ 559/2093] Compiling src/mymodule/model/ssd_clean.c
[ 560/2093] Compiling src/mymodule/model/ssd_gang.c
[ 561/2093] Compiling src/mymodule/model/ssd_timing.c
[ 564/2093] Compiling src/mymodule/model/ssd_init.c
[ 581/2093] Compiling install-ns3-header: ns3/ssdmodel_ssd_param.h
[1995/2093] Linking build/libns3.26-mymodule-debug.so
src/mymodule/model/ssdmodel_ssd_param.c.1.o:(.data+0x1c0): multiple definition of `SSDMODEL_SSD_loaders'
src/mymodule/model/ssdmodel_ssd_param.c.1.o:(.data+0x1c0): first defined here
src/mymodule/model/ssdmodel_ssd_param.c.1.o:(.data+0x240): multiple definition of `SSDMODEL_SSD_deps'
src/mymodule/model/ssdmodel_ssd_param.c.1.o:(.data+0x240): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You've only shown 1 .c file. It has definitions for SSDMODEL_SSD_loaders and SSDMODEL_SSD_deps. Apparently you have definitions for those same objects in some other .c file(s). Keep the declaration in the .h file, but remove the duplicate definitions - so you have only 1 definition each in a .c file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I took a careful look at the wscript file I wrote, which is an ns3 automatic compilation script. I carelessly imported the file ssdmodel_ssd_param.c  into it twice, so there was an error when I linked it. Now that the problem has been solved, thank you very much and good luck! !